# Override Sign in functionality of Spree / spree_auth_devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, spree

This is my signin page :

```
<%= form_for Spree::User.new, :as => :spree_user, :url => spree.spree_user_session_path  do |f| %>

        <%= f.email_field :email %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>

    <%= f.submit Spree.t(:login) %></p>

<% end %>
```

Created user_sessions_controller_decorator.rb file in controller section.

```
Spree::UserSessionsController.class_eval do

      def create
          @user = Spree::User.new
          @user.email  =  params['spree_user']['email']
            @user.password = params['spree_user']['password']
          authenticate_spree_user(@user)      

            if spree_user_signed_in?
                # sign_in(:spree_user, @user)
              redirect_to dashboards_profile_path
            else
                redirect_to user_signin_path
            end
    end
end
```

It's throwing error, 
Giving Error : NoMethodError (undefined method `authenticate_spree_user' for #):

I am unsure how to override spree login functionality & how to authenticate a user during sign in process.

Answer (score 2):

The method you are trying to use is `authenticate_spree_user!`.

I suggest you to check user_sessions_controller into spree_auth_devise [source code](https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise/blob/master/app/controllers/spree/user_sessions_controller.rb)

Comment: I checked the link. But I am confused here regarding overriding authentication. I am unsure shall I override spree authentication or over ride the spree_auth..would you please redirect me to some simpler blog post, I can take a look @ it ?

Comment: Which part of the authentication do you want to override?